# Using ASP.NET MVC to develop Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

EDIT: I am looking to develop a Web Form / Application with below requirements:

> 1) A Web form/application that connects to oracle / Sql database.
>
> 2) Thin Client (end client) should requires nothing but a web browser to run my Web form/application (i.e. .NET framework / API not required).  Browsers include phone browsers (i.e. Safari)
>
> 3) The form/app will be hosted using IIS (7.0 or above), and generate output (PDFs) to local share drives.

Should I go with ASP.NET MVC?  (instead of opinion-based question, I am merely asking if ASP.NET MVC fulfill the requirement listed).

I am familiar with C# and Visual studio development environment.  Problem is I had a window form successfully built with *Window forms application* and fails because end user requires .NET framework to run the xbap file used in the html page.  I am looking for an answer such as "No, you shouldn't use it because it cannot do all these thus doesn't met with requirement #3".

Also resources on form / app development that includes section on Phone browser config are very welcome.

Comment: and I got a downvote 2 sec after the question posted.  Downvoter please enlighten me on improvement, thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question is very broad and opinion based.  There's no specific programming problem listed, so it really doesn't belong here on SO.  It might go somewhere else?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @TLS yes I am wondering if this is the correct forum to post, as I couldn't find like ASP.NET META forum.  Please let me know should I move to some place that's meant for this kind of questions.

Comment: @PaulAbbott I have edited the question, hopefully I have narrowed down on the question being asked

Comment: @Alex - your title is a little misleading.  ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web Forms are two separate technology stacks - in the later versions of VS I believe you can use both in the same project, but there is no direct correlation between the two that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Tim thanks Tim, I have edited the title.  I google a bit on ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC and I still couldn't tell if ASP.NET MVC is the solution.  And yes, I can see that both are available in VS 2013

Comment: Both WebForms and MVC meet your requirements, which consist solely of "building a web page that accepts form input" and subsequently "processing that form input".  There's nothing about the scenario that precludes either option, and there's nothing specific to your question that would indicate one approach as being more suitable than the other.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer Thanks Joshua, what you and Matthew mentioned is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.net MVC is, in very big part, a glorified HTTP handler. It's very glorified, and it does a lot of cool things on top of that, but at the end of the day, that's what you're looking at: you write a method in a special class, and when you file an HTTP request against the server, it will call that method with some parameters, and expect you to return something it can turn into a response.

To that end, you'll have no more difficulty enabling cross-platform capabilities using MVC than you would using any other web server framework.

So the short answer is "yes," this should definitely work. And in fact, all that glorification on top of the HTTP handler will help you accomplish what you're looking for.

But don't be misled, because a website is a *very* different beast from a Windows Forms app, and the philosophies you'll take going into them are very different.

If I were you, I'd create an MVC project now, look up a tutorial, and make a quick site that just does something simple, like a to-do list or something. That should give you an awesome start to understanding the strengths and limitations of this platform.

But to answer the question you're asking, yes, this is a reasonable path of research for you to accomplish the goals you've put forward.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, this is indeed what I'm looking for, and definitely the approach you described.